# Word minimal table column width

Tags: microsoft-word, table-styles

Can you change the column width in a Word table to smaller than .29"? I want to use it as a spacer because the margin settings affect the entire table.

Comment: *Can you change the column width in a Word table to smaller than .29"?* No problems. 1) Set paragraph margins to 0; 2) Set table cells margins to 0 (Table properties - Table tab - Parameters knob - left/right fields margins by default); 3) Set column width as you need. Tested - 0.5 mm width was set successfully.

Comment: *I want to use it as a spacer* Do not use separate column for that purpose. Simply set right margin line of previous column (or left margin line for next column) to the width/pattern/color you want.

Answer (score 0):

> Can you change the column width in a Word table to smaller than .29"?

Of course. To do this:

1. Select the entire column you want to resize;
2. Right click the selection and choose **Table properties**;
3. In the **Column tab**, you will be able to set the column width to the desired value.

> I want to use it as a spacer because the margin settings affect the entire table.

Not the best solution. Select the table, go to **Paragraph**, in the main tab and set everything you want from there.